# Android VideoView starting lots of videos sequentially

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm testing this for about three days nonstop.

Here's the simple code:

```
private VideoView videoView;
```

--

```
videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            getNewVideo();
        }
    }
});

getNewVideo();
```

--

```
private void getNewVideo(){
    File file = //Any File. I have a list of files and they are executed in order
    videoView.stopPlayback();
    videoView.setVideoPath(file.getPath());
    videoView.start();
}
```

--

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

I need to execute this code 24/7.

The thing is, independent of duration (in the very beggining, or after 20 minutes running), SOMETIMES, the video just freezes. There's no log, there's no exception, the only thing i know is the last thing that is running before freezes is onPrepared().

The log is the same to all attempts to call the video, the only difference is that the last attemps (the one that freezes), is just stops after on prepared is executed.

ANY tip is appreciated.

The build number im using is RKM MK902_ANDROID5.1.1-20151016.1805

with a RKM MK902II Android PC device, running in a TV Screen 42'

Comment: The only thing I can recommend is to try another player, ExoPlayer2 should give you all the functionality, maybe some implementations of ExoPlayer could give you more than you need (playlist, etc).

Comment: I have the same problem. Also tried ExoPlayer v2 with no success. What I'm thinking is an OOM happening in the background with the videos in the native media player and since ExoPlayer also uses that, it won't help imo.

Comment: I think I got closer to the solution (or rather the bug), however, I don't know if it affects you, since I'm using Android 4.2 and 4.4. From the logs I see that most probably the Audio HAL crashes. It seems like the videos eventually *exploit* the stagefright bug (or something similar to that), producing buffer overflow, which crashes the mediaserver, and thus the whole application. I'm now testing a solution by disabling audio decoding in libvlc entirely, hopefully it solves the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have much experience playing local video files (I assume this because your code says you have a "list of files executed in order"), but.....

In my experience you shouldn't call `videoView.start()` until the media has been properly initialized by the VideoView.

When you call `videoView.setVideoPath("path")` the VideoView will do some initialization procedures to load the Media.  After VideoView has loaded/initialized the media it will then invoke its onPreparedListener callback (if you've set one).  Only when this callback has been invoked by the VideoView should you call `VideoView.start()` to start video playback.

So...when you set the onCompletionListener on your VideoView... you should also set an onPreparedListener.  When the VideoView reports back to your class that it's prepared....call `VideoView.start()` to start playback.

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoView.start();
        }
    }
});
```

Also, in my code I make a call to `VideoView.suspend()` before I re-use the VideoView to play a subsequent video.  Try adding a call to `VideoView.suspend()` in the beginning of your `getNewVideo()` method.

Comment: I did this, but it was not the cause of the problem. Same problem happening.

Comment: When you say the video just "freezes"....can you be a bit more descriptive?  Is audio still playing?  Also, provide some log data from before the point of failure to after the point of failure.  There may be something in there that you're just not giving credence.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
   videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {

                getNewVideo();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: All this would essentially do is handle the error and start playing the next video.  The poster not only needs to handle errors, but also know why his videos aren't playing.

Comment: the problem can that the user is using unsupported video format by the media player ,